# Bluetooth speakers , bluetooth headphones falls into Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm building an application on IOS  that searches for all Bluetooth devices nearby (smart band, Bluetooth speaker, mobile phones, etc.), but a few of them appear with names and the rest of them don't show their name. I could not find any of my Bluetooth speaker, mobiles or a laptop. Apple products show their name after connection, smart watches show their name at first but Bluetooth devices like a speaker or Huawei mobile don't show up. So I want to know whether these devices fall in BLE category or not. If not, then how to search for these devices?

I followed the documentation of core Bluetooth provided by Apple .

```
extension SearchDevicesViewController : CBCentralManagerDelegate , CBPeripheralManagerDelegate{

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

    switch (central.state) {
        case .poweredOff :
            print("bluetooth is off ")
            self.searchedPeripherals.removeAll()
        case .poweredOn :
            print("bluetooth is on ")           
            manager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil,  options: [ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])
    }
}
```

Expected result: peripheral comes up with a name.

Actual result: most of them show `Null` in their names.

Comment: You have two issues here.  The first is that, generally, speakers use legacy Bluetooth protocols and will not show up as BLE devices. The second is that there is limited space in the advertising packet and so you will not always see a name for a device

Comment: Continuing Paul's point, it's not possible to build this app on iOS; you cannot scan for classic devices. What problem are you trying to solve? There may be other solutions. What will the user do with the information?

Comment: @RobNapier actually we are trying to build an app that helps users to find their bluetooth devices. Like if someone lost his/her BT headphones, BT speaker , BT Earbuds or any other bluetooth device they open our application, scan for devices and follow the signal strength to locate that device. So, i need to show the names of devices wether it is BLE or not.

Comment: @Paulw11 i'm getting names of BLE devices but i need to deal with Legacy devices (classic bluetooth) . i have tried External Accessory framework , Core Bluetooth but still not found any solution

Comment: This can't be done on an iPhone. While there is now some limited BR/EDR (Classic) support in iOS 13, there is still no access to the scanner.

Comment: @RobNapier there must be some way, as iphone's bluetooth is able to identify all nearby devices . Anyway, Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that the OS can't identify devices. I'm saying that as an app developer, you do not have access to that layer of the OS. Non-Apple apps cannot do what you're trying to do as of iOS 13.